# Mysql combinations for 2 data sets

Tags: mysql, data-structures, combinations, permutation

I would like a table or query in mysql of all permutations of two separate datasets, but with rules.

I have a table of jobs, and a table of drivers.

I'd like to produce table or query of all combinations of jobs to drivers. Each job must have a driver, but each driver doesn't necessarily need a job. Like this:
In this example I have 4 jobs and 3 drivers.

```
Job1 | Job2 | Job3 | Job4
 1      1      1      1
 1      1      1      2
 1      1      1      3
 1      1      2      1
 1      1      3      1
```

This, I can't do, so if someone could help me that would be awesome. I believe that the number of rows in this example would be 4 to the power 3 (jobs to the power of drivers) which is 64 rows.

But the second part of this is what I call the "rules". Each job will have defined drivers that can do the job.

For example Job 1 can only be done by driver 1 or 3.
Job 2 can only be done by driver 1.
etc

I was thinking that if I did a create table, then running delete queries, but I am really at a loss. I would like to just create the query using the rules to start with in an attempt to speed it up.

This will eventually help me to make a plan for each job by showing all the ways that these jobs can be assigned.

Sorry for being vague but I'm hoping the community can help me out here.

Edit:
I think my maths may have been wrong. According to this: [combination calculator](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html) where I input 3 to choose from (drivers) and 4 numbers chosen (jobs) order is important and repetition is allowed (not sure what that is) then it produces 81.

Comment: current table layout is needed - or is there none currently and the structure is part of the Q?

Comment: @AxelAmthor Hi, I don't have any table structures.

Comment: @user2803146 . . . Why is this tagged with mysql if you are not using a database?

Comment: ok, so this isn't actually a DB related question but more or less one about basic data structures. What programming language? This is a basic requisite in order to get at least some answers here?

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is using a mysql database of data of the jobs, and drivers among other things. The structure is not important as I can change the tables and input methods to fit around any solutions or ideas anyone has to achieve this.

Comment: @AxelAmthor same as above

Answer (score 0):

Although way unclear and smells like homework, her my two cents:

Setup one table with the jobs `jobs`:

```
job_id|job_name
```

Next, set up a table with `drivers`:

```
driver_id|driver_name
```

Now we need to maps:

First the "rules", drivers which are capable of jobs, `job_capabilities`:

```
driver_id|job_id
```

this will contain one row for each assignment job => driver, the combination `(job_id, driver_id)` should be unique - one driver is only one times capable of a particular job.

Second map contains the assignments itself, `assigned_jobs`:

```
driver_id|job_id
```

actually that has the same layout, but for a given time period (which is missing here) one driver actually can only work on one job, so `driver_id` and a date-time should be unique. Skipped for clearness now.

Now we can construct an SQL like

```
  SELECT job_capabilities.driver_id, job.job_id from jobs, job_capabilities
     where job.job_id = job_capabilities.job_id
               AND job.job_id = 42;
```

We could just use that to insert into `assigned_jobs` with

```
  INSERT INTO assigned_jobs .... (Select from above) ...
```

probably enhanced by a `ON DUPLACET KEY UPDATE ...` clause.

To now get the assigned jobs, we can alter that statement a bit:

```
  SELECT assigned_jobs.driver_id, drivers.driver_name, job.job_id, job.job_name 
     from drivers, jobs, assigned_jobs
       where job.job_id = assigned_jobs.job_id
            AND drivers.driver_id = assigned_jobs.driver_id
               AND job.job_id = 42;
```

This is not tested and probably not valid SQL, but a first approach I would use.